# /var/www Directory not found

Tags: ubuntu

I do not have a /var/www directory in my ubuntu.
Isn't it a default directory which comes with os installation.

I am sorry if the question is silly or has already been asked. I ended up asking here after not getting any solution elsewhere.

Comment: `mkdir /var/wwww` and you'll have one. There must be something else you're really asking, something like 'how do I configure the root of my nginx` or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shravya,

www directory is the web root for applications, you need to `**install apache**` on your ubuntu in order to get the www directory.

it in not there by default.

Comment: I see this even after install `apache2`

Answer (score 4):

`/var/www` is Apache's default root and not Linux / Ubuntu's.

Other Webservers might use different directories aswell, e.g. NGINX uses `/usr/share/nginx/html` by default.

If you want to create that directory, simply run:

```
mkdir /var/www
```